# Is array_diff_uassoc and similar really a variadic function?

Tags: php, function

In the documentation on
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-uassoc.php
the signature

```
array_diff_uassoc(array $array, array ...$arrays, callable $key_compare_func): array
```

is given, but I can't get it to take more than three arguments. Given that "..." is supposedly only possible for the last parameter the signature should be incorrect in the first place. Is the documentation wrong? If not: How does one call array_diff_uassoc with more than two arrays as input?

I tried <s>putting in more than three parameters and</s> parameter unpacking but only got errors.

*I messed up and actually had an error in my callback function. The answer still has additional useful information for me.*

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO) and thanks for asking, nice question and thinking: If you write what did not work, it is okay to illustrate it with the non-working code, as it often speaks more. And it is fine to post non-working code on SO. E.g. I can now only post an answer that shows that it works with more than three arrays, however don't know why it didn't work for you. That just as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've read that correct:

```php
array_diff_uassoc(array $array, array ...$arrays, callable $key_compare_func): array
```

```
(array $array, array ...$arrays,
```

Means that you need at minimum one array (actually two or more make sense, but one is *required*).

As last argument then is the callable, required as well.

You can't use argument unpacking (...$arrays) before another argument, therefore the ...$array in the manual only shows that there are zero or more array arguments following, not that it can be called with argument unpacking.

Examples:

```php
array_diff_uassoc([], $callable);
array_diff_uassoc([], [], $callable);
array_diff_uassoc([], [], [], $callable);
array_diff_uassoc([], [], [], [], $callable);
# ...
```

3v4l.org demo: https://3v4l.org/vHi8v

---

And your question:

> Is array_diff_uassoc and similar really a variadic function?

Yes, those are variadic functions.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know unpacking had to be done last, but given how it's most often used it makes sense. Regarding why putting in more parameters didn't work for me: I did not expect a standard function to change it's behavior within a major version and therefore only checked that I had php 8. 3v4l.org will enter my workflow for testing from now on

Comment: It's worth noting that in _user-defined_ functions only the last positional argument can be variable-length. PHP core/extension functions have much more free reign in how they can be defined, as above with `array_diff_uassoc()` which long predates variadic functions' implementation into PHP.

Comment: @Sammitch: That's a fine remark on the internals, from PHP userland it makes not much of a difference though, `array_diff_uassoc(...[[], [], []], $callable)` raises _"Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking"_ (also variations with named parameters - unfortunately!)

Comment: Ah and not to create a wrong impression here: `array_diff_uassoc(...[[], [], [], $callable])` or `array_diff_uassoc(...[[], [], []], ...[$callable])` naturally works.